# Can i save files to a usb drive in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, usb-drive

I am trying to make a recipe database for my grandma and I would like to learn how to save the recipes to an sd card.

Comment: When you ask a question, please add in more supporting brief for your problem. Any codes, images etc that can help us understand you problem better and come with a resolution. Also, add in your own research that you did in order to get this problem resolved, this will help us what Not to quote as an answer that has already been tried or researched on. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use open method, see below

```
with open(usb_drive_location, "wb+") as file_obj:
    file_obj.write(uploaded_file.file.read())
```

just add in your usb_drive_location and you will be good.